# Droidcam - error inserting module / v4l2loopback problem - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: droidcam

I am trying to install Droidcam on my Ubuntu 20.04 but I can't.
I have this on Terminal:

Registering webcam device
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/5.4.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/media/video/v4l2loopback-dc.ko: Operation not permitted
warning: insmod failed

I don't know what I did wrong. I think maybe because of Secure Boot. I would be appreciate if anyone tries to help. Thank you

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to paste in the exact commands you ran?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last weeks and I was finally able to solve it by disabling Secure Boot. It is not advisable to do so, but I was really getting annoyed by not being able to install DroidCam, and wasn't able to find how to properly path Security Keys.

In my case, I disabled Secure Boot following the steps in "Method 2" in the next webpage:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS

Then, I uninstalled and installed again DroidCam, following closely every step in the page. And that was all, now I can use with ease my Android as a Webcam in my Xubuntu Laptop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your time. I was able to run the app when I disabled it, but I don't want to disable the secure boot. I don't know if I can find a solution.

Comment: Have you found anything? I tried different solutions, but also didnt found any that doesnt get into disabling the secure boot.